# Find specific chart's coordinate

Tags: python

I need to scan a list of few strings (each row is string), find the symbol "+" or "@" (only one of them can appear), and print the x,y coordinate. The left corner is (0,0) and if you keep right and down the values are increase.

I don't understand what is wrong with my code:

```
    x,y=-1,-1
    for row in my_list:  
            y+=1
            for symbol in row:
                    x+=1
                    if symbol=="@":
                            makom=(x,y)
                            player="@"       
                    if symbol=="+":
                            makom=(x,y)
                            player="+"


     print makom
```

list:

```
####
# .#
#  ###
#*@  #
#  $ #
#  ###
####
```

output:

```
(2,3)
```

Comment: You can make your code much clearer by using the `enumerate()` builtin rather than manually counting.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: we didnt learn it, so I rather not using it @Lattyware

Comment: You mean the word "coordinate"?

Comment: Well, I wasn't talking exactly about the spelling... If what you need is to show the word coordinate, try print "coordinate: %s" % makom (instead of print makom) at the end of your code

Comment: As I mentioned it, this done using `enumerate()` - http://ideone.com/TqokbE

Comment: haha tnx anyway @BorrajaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reset `x` while changing rows:

```
y = -1
for row in my_list:  
        x = -1
        y += 1
        for symbol in row:
                x += 1
                if symbol == "@":
                        makom = (x,y)
                        player = "@"       
                if symbol == "+":
                        makom = (x,y)
                        player = "+"


print makom
```

Just for completeness, you wouldn't have made this mistake if you used `enumerate` :D

```
for y, row in enumerate(my_list):
        for x, symbol in enumerate(row):
                if symbol == "@":
                        makom = (x, y)
                        player = "@"       
                if symbol == "+":
                        makom = (x, y)
                        player = "+"


print makom
```